# How to find the div inside the texarea content and replace the style using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the textarea element below :

```
 <table><tr><td><textarea class="text_popup" id="script" ><script src="script.js"></script><script>$(document).ready(function(){$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"300px", height:"500px",});});</script><a class="main"><div id="new_text_val">test</div></a></textarea></td></tr></table>



$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:    "newpage.php",
            async: true,
            data: 'name=' + name +'&age=' + age , 
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){                     
              // response  data  
                    }
            });
```

after the ajax success `<div id="new_text_val">test</div>` should be replaced to success response data

final replace looks like below

```
<table><tr><td><textarea class="text_popup" id="script" ><script src="script.js"></script><script>$(document).ready(function(){$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"300px", height:"500px",});});</script><a class="main">ajax succes resonse data </a></textarea></td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

First put the new element after the current element and then remove the current element.

```
$('#new_text_val')
    .after('<div class="inside_text"><div><img src=image.png></div></div>')
    .remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your success function:

```
$('#new_text_val').parent().html(" <div class='inside_text'><div><img src=image.png></div></div> " );
```

It is very hard to read your question btw.